# Django: order a queryset by the sum of annotated fields?

Tags: python, sql, django, django-orm

I'm building a Django site for discussions.  Users can participate in discussions and can also cast votes of approval for discussions and messages in the discussions.  A simplified data model is as follows:

```
class Discussion:
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)

class Message:
    owner = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='messages')
    body = models.TextField()
    discussion = models.ForeignKey(Discussion, related_name='messages')

class MessageApprovalVote:
    owner = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='message_approval_votes')
    message = models.ForeignKey(Message, related_name='approval_votes')

class DiscussionApprovalVote:
    owner = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='discussion_approval_votes')
    discussion = models.ForeignKey(Discussion, related_name='approval_votes')
```

I want to select the top 20 "most active" discussions, which means ordering by the sum of the number of messages, total number of message approval votes, and number of discussion approval votes for that discussion, or (in pseudocode):

```
# Doesn't work
Discussion.objects.
    order_by(Count('messages') + 
             Count('approval_votes') + 
             Count('messages__approval_votes'))
```

Using annotations, I can calculate the totals of each of the three scoring factors:

```
scores = Discussion.objects.annotate(
    total_messages=Count('messages', distinct=True),
    total_discussion_approval_votes=Count('approval_votes', distinct=True),
    total_message_approval_votes=Count('messages__approval_votes', distinct=True))
```

I then thought I was on to something when I found the `extra` method:

```
total_scores = scores.extra(
    select={
        'score_total': 'total_messages + total_discussion_approval_votes + total_message_approval_votes'
    }
)
```

and would then be able to do:

```
final_answer = total_scores.order_by('-score_total')[:20]
```

but the `extra` call gives a `DatabaseError`:

```
DatabaseError: column "total_messages" does not exist
LINE 1: SELECT (total_votes + total_messages + total_persuasions) AS...
```

and thus I was foiled.  Can the `extra` method not reference `annotate`d fields?  Is there another way to do what I'm trying to do, short of using a raw sql query?  I'm using Postgres if that makes a difference.

Any insights would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/aggregation/#aggregating-annotations Is this not helpful enough ?

Comment: An aggregate doesn't seem like it will help in this case because I need to get back a queryset of the Discussion objects, not just the counts of each scoring factor.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think this is possible in a single top-level SQL query. The score_total value depends on the three aggregate results, but you're asking them all to be calculated at the same time.

In straight SQL, you can do this with a subquery, but I'm not sure how to inject it into Django. After setting up a simple Django app with your models, the following query seems to do the trick against a SQLite database:

```
SELECT  id, name,
    total_messages, total_discussion_approval_votes, total_message_approval_votes,
    (total_messages +
     total_discussion_approval_votes +
     total_message_approval_votes) as score_total
FROM
   (SELECT
    discussion.id,
    discussion.name,
    COUNT(DISTINCT discussionapprovalvote.id) AS total_discussion_approval_votes,
    COUNT(DISTINCT messageapprovalvote.id) AS total_message_approval_votes,
    COUNT(DISTINCT message.id) AS total_messages
    FROM discussion
    LEFT OUTER JOIN discussionapprovalvote
         ON (discussion.id = discussionapprovalvote.discussion_id)
    LEFT OUTER JOIN message
         ON (discussion.id = message.discussion_id)
    LEFT OUTER JOIN messageapprovalvote
         ON (message.id = messageapprovalvote.message_id)
    GROUP BY discussion.id, discussion.name)

ORDER BY score_total DESC
LIMIT 20;
```

Comment: It's easy to run this from Django using a [raw SQL query](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/sql/):   `Discussion.objects.raw('''SELECT ... etc ...''')`

Answer (score 1):

Actually there's a way by using an extra annotate with [F expressions](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/expressions/#django.db.models.F):

```
Discussion.objects.annotate(
    total_messages=Count('messages', distinct=True),
    total_discussion_approval_votes=Count('approval_votes', distinct=True),
    total_message_approval_votes=Count('messages__approval_votes', distinct=True)),
    total_score=F('total_messages') + F('total_discussion_approval_votes') + F('total_message_approval_votes')
).order_by('total_score')
```

Comment: Technically, those should be inside an `ExpressionWrapper` in case you need any form of casting, etc